# Not able to save page in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

At the end, I am not able to click on save button. The last click is not working for me.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "C:\\Users\\gausia.fatima\\Downloads\\automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://www.idfystaging.com/users/sign_in");
      driver.findElement(By.name("user[login]")).sendKeys("themanager@mailinator.com");
       driver.findElement(By.name("user[password]")).sendKeys("Password123");
       driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
       driver.get("http://www.idfystaging.com/profiles/new?company_id=189");
       Select mydrpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company_id")));
       mydrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("Fringe A Division");
       driver.findElement(By.id("email_addresses")).sendKeys("awesome1@mailinator.com");
       driver.findElement(By.id("counts_aadhaar")).sendKeys("1");
       //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("commit")));
      driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).submit();
      System.out.println("candiate is invited.");
      //driver.close();
```

Comment: Can you please format the code?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Invite Candidates" page, you have to submit button with the same name as "commit", so selenium is throwing error.
http://www.idfystaging.com/profiles/new?company_id=189

Use the CssSelectorto get the control and submit them.

Java code un tested but it should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.f21")).Submit();
```

Note : This is c# code and I tested

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.f21")).Submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

as `name=commit` returns two elements in the page, should use more strict selector to find the Invite button.

Try the following code to click on `Invite` button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Invite']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Invite']")).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code. I have modified it and it is working fine. Please check if it is working fo you.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "C:\\Users\\gausia.fatima\\Downloads\\automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.idfystaging.com/users/sign_in");
driver.findElement(By.id("focus_on_load")).sendKeys("themanager@mailinator.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("Password123");
driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.navigate().to("http://www.idfystaging.com/profiles/new?company_id=189");

Select mydrpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company_id")));
mydrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("Fringe A Division");
driver.findElement(By.id("email_addresses")).sendKeys("awesome1@mailinator.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("counts_aadhaar")).sendKeys("1");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.f21")).click();
System.out.println("candiate is invited.");
```